# .Net error en el model container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, servicio

No logro ver el error, me lo marca en: `= ctx.spObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidar_sUP(Operador);` ya intenté de todo:

```
ctx.spObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidar_sUP(Operador)
public List<CivarTransporteService.Model.SPObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidarResult> getCombustibleSinLiquidar(int Operador)
{
    using (CivarTransporteService.Model.SIAModelContainer ctx = new CivarTransporteService.Model.SIAModelContainer())
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<CivarTransporteService.Model.SPObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidarResult> spResult =  ctx.spObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidar_sUP(Operador);
            return spResult.ToList();       
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Agrego detalles:

```
namespace CivarTransporteService.Model
{
    using System;

    public partial class SPObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidarResult
    {
        public int Operador { get; set; }
    }
}
```

El *Stored Procedure* solo pide como parámetro el operador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola.. Mira, no podemos ayudar salvo que sepamos mucho mas. Desde acá tampoco logramos ver el error. Ni nada que se le parezca... Trata de formular tu pregunta completa y con todos los datos necesarios para que sepamos que pasa y asi poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Te está enviando ese error debido a que el método `spObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidar_sUP` tiene como valor de retorno un `int` y tu estás esperando un `IEnumerable<CivarTransporteService.Model.SPObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidarResult>`

Para esto, hay dos posibles soluciones:

1. El método `spObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidar_sUP` deberá regresar una variable de tipo `IEnumerable<CivarTransporteService.Model.SPObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidarResult>`
2. Al invocar el método `spObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidar_sUP` se deberá hacer a través de una variable de tipo `int`, por ejemplo:

   `int result = ctx.spObtieneCombustibleSinLiquidar_sUP(Operador);`